# Rails gems break after Ruby version update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, rubygems

We're running a legacy Rails application that we recently updated from Rails 4 to Rails 6.

When trying to update it to version 7 however, it seems like we need do change the Ruby version. Using rbenv it's simple:

```
rbenv local 2.7.4
```

After that we tried to run `bundle install` with updated Gemfile and got the following error:

```bash
    current directory: /home/petarangelov/Desktop/dev/realappeal-esra/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/skylight-5.0.1/ext
/home/petarangelov/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/ruby -I /home/petarangelov/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20230504-290002-1y0acei.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/XX/XX/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/XX/XX/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream': undefined method `parse' for #<Psych::Parser:0x000055c964928528> (NoMethodError)
```

Seems like it's being caused by `skylight` although I don't see the reason why doesn't it compile properly.

The updated Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rubocop'
gem 'pry'
gem 'aasm', '~> 5.0'
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'american_date'
gem "audited"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0'
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.5.1', group: :development
gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.8.0', group: :development
gem 'byebug'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'
gem 'capybara', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'capybara-screenshot', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false, group: [:development, :test]
gem 'daemons'
gem 'database_cleaner', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'ddtrace'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.7.3'
gem 'devise-async', git: 'https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async.git', ref: '177f6363a002f7ff28f1d289c8cab7ad8d9cb8c5'
gem 'devise-security'
gem 'factory_bot_rails', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'faker', group: [:development, :test, :staging]
gem 'fixedwidth', git: 'https://github.com/gristmill/fixedwidth.git', ref: '82575c2d6faa2d1aa82158147c5268f0d4f673bd'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'launchy', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'lograge'
gem 'logstash-event'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'omniauth-azure-activedirectory'
gem 'omniauth-saml'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 6.1'
gem 'poltergeist', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'rails', '7.0'
gem 'rails-erd'
gem 'rspec-rails', '> 5', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'ruby-kafka'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 1.0', group: :doc
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'simplecov', require: false, group: :test
gem 'skylight'
gem 'spring', group: :development
gem 'stupidedi'
gem 'timecop', group: :test
gem 'thread_safe'
gem 'trix'
gem 'validates_timeliness'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.6'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jc-validates_timeliness'

gem 'after_commit_everywhere'
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
gem 'will_paginate'
```

Any clues as to where does this come from will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is this on Mac M1/M2?

Comment: I would update skylight as well and see if that helps. 5.0.1 was released 2 years ago. Current version is 5.3.4.

Comment: Does the `mkmf.log` file contain any more hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[skylight](https://rubygems.org/gems/skylight) is currently 5.3.4 and claims compatibility with Ruby `>= 2.6`,

[skylight 5.0.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/skylight/versions/5.0.1) claims compatibility with  Ruby `>= 2.5`, indicating a breaking change between 2.5 and 2.6.

This is likely [confirmed by this issue](https://github.com/skylightio/skylight-ruby/issues/352) with v5.1.0 not working with Ruby 2.5.x, given then changes to `Psyche`

And it appears you have a similar issue:

```bash
ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream': undefined method `parse' for #<Psych::Parser:0x000055c964928528> (NoMethodError)
```

I usually follow this pattern:

1. Install my desired Ruby version
2. Remove all version constraints from my Gemfile
3. Do `bundle install` on my desired Ruby version
4. Re-lock my gem versions (though I only soft-lock to minor versions)